# How to write an initializer for a class with many properties in Python?

Tags: python, sdk

I'm building an SDK around a REST API which is unchangeable (i.e. I can't change the schema). Some models in the API have about twenty properties, all with public getters and setters.

1 or 2 of these properties are non-nullable so they need to be positional arguments in the `__init__` method. The other properties are optional so they can be keyword arguments. However an `__init__` method with 19 keyword arguments seems clunky. For example:

```
def __init__(self, req_prop, opt_prop1=None, opt_prop2=None, ...):
    self._req_prop = req_prop
    self._opt_prop1 = opt_prop1
    self._opt_prop2 = opt_prop2
    ...
```

I thought the above implementation would be easier for developers using an IDE with method hints. Alternatively, I could use **kwargs:

```
def __init__(self, req_prop, **kwargs):
    self._req_prop = req_prop
    self._opt_prop1 = None
    self._opt_prop2 = None
    ...
    for key, value in **kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

This makes the `__init__` method more readable but requires developers to open up the file to examine the property names to pass as keyword arguments. Also, the IDE can't help with spelling.

One final option that would make the SDK code more concise and developer code more verbose is to force usage of property setters:

```
def __init__(self, req_prop):
    self._req_prop = req_prop
```

Which implementation is the most Pythonic and easiest for 3rd party developers? Please include citations if you have them.